# Unity 2019.2.0f1 Unable to locate Android NDK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-ndk

I am trying to test in app purchases in Unity **2019.2.0f1**, and when I try to build the apk, I keep getting error: **Unable to locate Android NDK** even though I downloaded **Android NDK r16b** and changed the path in **Edit --> Preferences --> External tools**

I searched alot and tried to install more than one version of NDK, and also tried to add the path of NDK in Environment Variables in settings of My Computer but the error kept showing.

Can someone please tell me how to solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue in Unity 2019.2.8f1 on mac. My solution is going to Edit --> Preferences --> External tools and uncheck "android NDK installed with Unity". Then add the specific NDK folder path in it. For me, it is
`/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.8f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/*android-ndk-r16b*`

Interestingly, the automatic setup by unity is `/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.8f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK/`
which missed the specific folder name `android-ndk-r16b`. So I just add `android-ndk-r16b` at the end of the last folder path. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, I have found that the build fails when I try to add the folder to the end of the path. I have found a solution here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/il2cpp-build-error-missing-libatomic-a.786005 - copy the content of the NDK/android-ndk-r16b into the NDK folder (so to the parent) and check installed with Unity tick again.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Unity Hub, you can just check the box where it sais add android support, that downloads everything you need for android development automatically.

[image: You can see this option under modules]

Comment: I already downloaded Android SDK & NDK Tools. Should I download also OpenJDK ?

Comment: Yes, you can try that as well. What is weird to me is that if you check all the boxes here, you don't need to set any paths later in preferences because unty sets it all up.

Answer (score 2):

Open unity hub > click install > click drop down menu in target unity > add modules > open drop down in android build support > check all sdk ndk download > proceed

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. I made a upgrade to version 2019.2.9f1 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried downgrading Unity version, changing path of NDK file and using other NDK files but none of them solved the problem.

After all, built the game in Windows machine instead of Mac and it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

during build android project in unity 2019 and  other new version >>Go to build setting>> then go to Other setting>> then scroll down || then see configuration >>  in configuration go to >> scripting backend select > mono rather then IL2CPP then select ARMV7 rather then ARM64 your problem definitely will be solved thank

sohaib kh

Comment: On google store now the apk needs to be build in both 32 and 64. In order to build on 64 it needs Scripting Backend as IL2CPP. As tou can see on https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Answer (score 0):

this description can work on << window>> moreover , In mac or other operating system You might be apply  : ILC2PP : or : ARMV7 : or : X86 : your problem definitely will be solved

---

during build android project in unity 2019 and  other new version >>Go to build setting>> then go to Other setting>> then scroll down || then see configuration >>  in configuration go to >> scripting backend select > mono rather then IL2CPP then select ARMV7 rather then ARM64 your problem definitely will be solved thank

---