# Multiple Errors Unity (SDK APP Building) (on Mac) See Pictures for information

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

I need some help, I turned on my USB-Debug in developer settings  on my android phone. I wanted to build a apk With Unity but in the end there were a couple error messages.

Main Message: Failed to Build APK see Console for more information. 
Can someone help me out?

[Errors Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaoYI.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Unity Hub, make sure you've downloaded the Android NDK and SDK Tools from Installs>Add Modules. Otherwise, you'll need to download those online if you haven't already. If those are already installed, check your preferences to see if Unity is looking in the right place for them. [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57347932/unity-2019-2-0f1-unable-to-locate-android-ndk) may be helpful to you (the answer by TLC is what helped me with a very similar issue!)